# Xcode add mutable dictionary from JSON to mutable array

Tags: json, xcode, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I have a mutable array stories that I'm trying to add a copy of JSON response to but it yields O stories and nothing in the array. What am I doing wrong? The JSON object is properly formatted and I can display each component individually but they will not add to the array.

```
NSString *str=@"http://www.foo.com/some.php";
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:str];
NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSError *error=nil;
NSMutableDictionary *response=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:
             NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

NSLog(@"Your JSON Object: %@", response);


NSLog(@"Location: %@", response[@"location"]);
NSLog(@"Service ID: %@", response[@"serviceID"]);
NSLog(@"Problem: %@", response[@"problem"]);

[stories addObject:[response copy] ];

NSLog(@"Workorders: %d", [stories count]);
NSLog(@"WO Defined: %@",stories);
```

Comment: Could you give an example of the JSON when you visit the page with a web browser?

Comment: Can you explain how are you initializing your mutable array : `stories`

Comment: Sorry, it is at the top of the file NSMutableArray *stories;

Comment: Looks like stories is not initialized. Because Objective C allows you send messages to nil objects you don't face any problem in call [stories addObject:[response copy]].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go...try this

```
NSMutableArray *stories = [NSMutableArray array];
```